# how to create a uiview with segues, which is used by multiple UIViewControllers in storyboard

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard

Basically what I want to do is to include UIView to multiple UIViewControllers on storyboard. I could include the uiview, but segues in the UIView doesn't work.
I have a storyboard something like this:
[image]

I have a tab controller with 2 UIViewControllers `First` and `Second`. And I have a separated UITableViewController with two another UIViewControllers `A` and `B`, connected with segues.

I could add the table view into `First` and `Second` views as a subview, but when I tap cell it doesn't go to next screen `A` or `B`. I sort of figured out why it didn't work, but just can't figure the best way to accomplish this.

Is there any good way to do this? I'm new to storyboard but have been developing iOS app for a while.

**EDIT:**

The way I add the tableViewController to each View is following:

```
self.tableViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"theTableViewController"];
[self.view addSubview:_tableViewController.tableView];
```

When a cell in the table view is tapped, prepareForSegue:segue:sender is invoked, but no push to navigation controller since the table view controller is sitting in each view controller as just a subview

**EDIT2:**

I posted my test project [here](http://blog.enjoitech.jp/upload/37_storyboard.zip)

Comment: How did you wire "Screen A" and "Screen B" to the tableView? Directly to the tableView cells?

Comment: @Rick yes they're connected to custom cells.

Comment: Since you are using storyboard, why not create separate tableViews in First and Second viewControllers and segue to "Screen A" and "Screen B"? You won't require a single line of code.

Comment: I simplified it for this question but actually there is not only A or B or First or Second.. There are many view controllers that will need the table view, and there are at least 5 custom cells and view controllers connected to segue each. that's why I am thinking to make just one table view controller with all necessary custom cells, and connect to view controller with segue.

Comment: Then, you will need to show the code on how the tableView is added to the view controller.

Comment: See if this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11978604/1479411) helps

Comment: yes, thanks @Rick. That's the way I would do if I did't use storyboard. I just wonder what storyboard and segue really are capable of. Since every transition in my code so far is working with segue, I didn't want to go back and create xib file and push view controller to navigation controller, just like I used to do..

Comment: @Rick thanks for you help. I just figured out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to make segue within sub views. It was actually very simple. It seems that I need to add the view controllers to the main view controller as a "childViewControllers"

instead of

```
self.tableViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"theTableViewController"];
```

I did like this:

```
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"theTableViewController"];
[self.view addSubview:_tableViewController.tableView];
```

and segues in the childViewController work as I expect. Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 methods you can try .

1.Create a segue between the tableview cell and next view controller directly. What I want to emphasize is the fact that do not create segue between the tableview or view and the next view controller,unless trying the method below.

2.Add this code to your tableview controller :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath row]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToB" sender:self];
    }else {
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToA" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have already connected cell and next view controllers directly by segue. also performSegueWithIdentifier doesn't work since the table view is added to each uiview as subview. push navigation thing doesn't work. that's the issue I am having here

Comment: It seems that only can call `pushViewController:animated:` in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` . I'll have a try.

Comment: hmm I see. I'll do some more research on it and decide what to do. I posted my test project. thanks!